# How to stop the inheritance of html elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm remaking google front page as an assignement and i stumbled upon something i don't completly understand.

One of my buttons does not get the same CSS properties as the other one, namely the "I'm feeling lucky" button

Here's jsfiddle of the webpage (doesn't look the same as on my browser)

http://jsfiddle.net/chrislotix/gvk1ka68/

Upon further inspection in google dev tools i stumbled upon this:

```
Inherited from a < -- This is what i assume is the main culprit
a:-webkit-any-link {
color: -webkit-link;
text-decoration: underline;
cursor: auto;
```

How do i make my second button CSS properties not inherit (from whatever it is)?

Bonus related question: What kind of approach would help me not have similar issues in the future?

Comment: This is not inheritance, it is simply CSS applied because of a matching selector. If you don’t like the formatting that results in, then you either have to modify the selector so that it does not match the element any more (not possible for styles coming from the browser stylesheet), or you have to overwrite the properties with values you like better.

Comment: So, you don't want an `a` element to use the CSS properties assigned to `a` elements? You can certainly use a [CSS reset](http://cssreset.com/) to "turn off" default styling, but you're going to experience a lot of frustration if you think that this is an "issue". Every browser has default styling for most, or all, elements. If you need radically different styles, you'll need to apply them yourself.

Comment: That is from the browser styles. if you want to override you can do #lucky a{your style properties} in your css file. Also, a CSS reset or Normalize is best practice to start with your styling.

Comment: You are applying styles to a global class. If you want to apply styles to a specific element, put an #id or .class to it and add your css there

Comment: @CBroe I might be misunderstanding something. Why do i have to overwrite the second button (the one which doesnt work the way i want) but not the first one?

Comment: @Lotix I think first you should inspect Google's home page. That might help you.

Comment: The problem in the fiddle is that the second `div` is inside the first `a`, because the first `a` doesn't have an end tag. If you add the end tag, the differences will go away.

Comment: And the answer to the bonus question is, validate your HTML.

Comment: @MrLister That indeed was the blunder. Much thanks to you and all others.